# Recovery options in Windows 10? Run from DOS or CLI how?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, data-recovery, system-restore, control-panel

How do I `Recover from a drive` through the CLI?  Because I'm just not seeing [this option](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options) in the Control Panel after reading the fine manual:

> You can also Recover from a drive. This will reinstall Windows 10
>   (unless your PC came with Windows 8/8.1 and a recovery partition from
>   your PC manufacturer, in which case it'll reinstall the version of
>   Windows that came with your PC). It'll also remove your personal
>   files, apps and drivers you installed, and changes you made to
>   settings.

I just didn't see any such option, although `System Restore` options were available.

Apparently, the partition before the ESP is Windows PE?  The second partition is the recovery partition itself:

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.14393.0

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: BUDDY

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   Acer         NTFS   Partition    915 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         Recovery     NTFS   Partition    600 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 2         ESP          FAT32  Partition    300 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 3         Push Button  NTFS   Partition     15 GB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4     D   Transcend    FAT32  Removable    117 GB  Healthy
```

[image]

*This is for Windows 10 and therefore UEFI and GPT.*

I forgot about `msconfig`, but what I'd like to see is this menu:

[image]

from:

http://www.howtogeek.com/126016/three-ways-to-access-the-windows-8-boot-options-menu/

The article says it applies to Windows 10.  Not sure.

Comment: I think you should recover from DOS

Comment: @Elie yes, but **how**?  I'll fire it up again and look in the GUI, but just didn't see it.

Comment: Try holding shift while you select restart and go to troubleshooting mode and select recover

Comment: I thought it was `F8`?  Which does nothing on this particular pc.

Comment: Not in windows 10 apparently

Comment: If it solves your problem mark the thread as answered

Comment: I won't be able to tell you until I try next week.  Thanks tho.

Comment: No worries keep us updated .